# Item unable to hide

Tags: html, asp.net, select

I am tried to hide an select item in asp.net.But it coudn't hide

My codes

```
<select runat="server" id="slct" >
        <option  value="2" runat="server">Admin</option>
        <option  value="3" runat="server">Theatreadmin</option>
        <option  value="4" runat="server">Movies</option>
</select>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        slct.Items[0].Attributes.Add("display","none");
    }
```

But its still visible,what went wrong for me?Any idea?

Comment: This can be done using Javascript/Jquery why rely on server?

Answer (score 0):

simple code `slct.Visible=False;`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        slct.Items[2].Enabled = true;
        slct.Items[2].Visible = false;
}
```

also javascript

```
$("#slct option[value='2']").hide();
```

Comment: :it will hide all option items,i only want to hide admin option,ie the first one.

Comment: your mistack Items[2] not [0]

Comment: i think your problem [0] change it slct.Items[2].Attributes.Add("display","none");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97638/discussion-between-denish-parvadia-and-unnikrishnan-s).